# Recognize fields from PDF,DOC and etc formats and export them to database

Tags: java, php, python

is anybody know the solution for reading file(for example pdf format, it has some tax information), recognize fields and write them to DB? It is similiar idea that FlexiCapture has.

Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get any answers to my question. So I did a little bit research and I think the answer to my question will be - OCR.

http://code.google.com/p/pytesser/

http://code.google.com/p/ocropus/

Hopefully I will start my testing soon. Thanks everybody!